# methods of declaring multiple variables

Tags: php

I have the following blocks of code:

```
$ship = $this->get_address($this->dealer_num);
$bill = $this->get_address($this->bill_to_num);

$this->ship_name =     $ship['CMNAME'];
$this->ship_address1 = $ship['CMLNE1'];
$this->ship_address2 = $ship['CMLNE2']!='' ? $ship['CMLNE2'] : NULL;
$this->ship_address3 = $ship['CMLNE2']!='' ? $ship['CMLNE3'] : NULL;
$this->ship_city =     $ship['CMCITY'];
$this->ship_state =    $ship['CMST'];
$this->ship_zip =      $ship['CMZIP'];
$this->ship_country =  $ship['CMCTRY'];

$this->bill_name =     $bill['CMNAME'];
$this->bill_address1 = $bill['CMLNE1'];
$this->bill_address2 = $bill['CMLNE2']!='' ? $bill['CMLNE2'] : NULL;
$this->bill_address3 = $bill['CMLNE3']!='' ? $bill['CMLNE3'] : NULL;
$this->bill_city =     $bill['CMCITY'];
$this->bill_state =    $bill['CMST'];
$this->bill_zip =      $bill['CMZIP'];
$this->bill_country =  $bill['CMCTRY'];
```

Here is the definition of get_address:

```
private function get_address($key) {
      $result = db_query('SELECT CMNAME, CMLNE1, CMLNE2,
                          CMLNE3, CMCITY, CMST, CMZIP, CMCTRY
                          FROM myTable
                          WHERE C1STKY = :key;',
                         array(':key' => $key));  
      $info = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      return $info;
}
```

What are my alternatives for declaring these variables? I hate the big long lists of just variable declarations. Is there a more elegant way to declare these?

Comment: Since you're using PDO and putting the information into an object, you could use PDO's `fetch_object` method and retrieve an object directly: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchobject.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I ultimately fixed this problem was changing my class definition. Rather than having class properties for each address component, I simply changed my class definition to store the address as an associative array. It felt much cleaner that way.

Thus, the above code became

```
$this->shipping_address = $this->get_address($this->dealer_num);
$this->billing_address = $this->get_address($this->bill_to_num);
```